# Why is the Angular 2 router updating the template but not the URL after manual change

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a couple routes like this...

```
[
    {
        path: "admin",
        component: ContentComponent,
        canActivate: [ CanActivateIfAuthenticated ],
        children: [
            {
                path: "",
                pathMatch: "full",
                redirectTo: "tenants",
            },
            {
                path: "tenants"
                component: TenantComponent
            }
         ]
    }
]
[
    {
        path: "other",
        component: ContentComponent,
        canActivate: [ CanActivateIfAuthenticated ],
        children: [
            {
                path: "",
                pathMatch: "full",
                redirectTo: "item",
            },
            {
                path: "item"
                component: ItemComponent
            }
         ]
    }
]
```

When I am on `/admin/tenants` and I manually change the url, the routerOutlet changes but the url remains `/admin/tenants`. However, when I change it back to `/admin` it goes to the `admin/tenants` screen but the url shows `/other/item`. Router.navigateByUrl does not seem to have the same issue. I am using the HashLocationStrategy and I have a base tag set so I don't think it is that issue.

Here is an update:

i have tracked it down to this code in Router...

`if (navigationIsSuccessful) {
  _this.routerEvents.next(new NavigationEnd(id, _this.serializeUrl(url), _this.serializeUrl(_this.currentUrlTree)));
  resolvePromise(true);
}
else {
  _this.resetUrlToCurrentUrlTree();
  _this.routerEvents.next(new NavigationCancel(id, _this.serializeUrl(url), ''));
  resolvePromise(false);
}`

`navigationIsSuccessful` is resolving to false and so it is calling the reset Url function. Then another (correct) one comes through but the url has already been reset. If I look where the bad request is coming from in terms of the callstack things get weirder still because the call stack suggest this line caused the runNavigate...

`notifications = new Subject();
...
this.notifications.next({
            isAuthenticated : exp,
            message: message,
        });`

That doesn't seem like something that should cause a navigation.

Comment: "and I manually change the url," - to what value?

Comment: Per the description if I am on the /admin/tenants route I would change it to /other. If I was on the /other/item route it would be /admin. I have a bunch more routes but just trying to simplify it a bit here. The moral is that the url that is displayed in the bar reverts back to the previous url. I see it "snap" back once I hit enter to navigate.

Comment: Also it should be noted that these are each in their own Routing module and imported into a common routing module (which is eventually imported by my main module)

Answer (score 1):

I had to upgrade from router v 3.3.0 to v 3.4.1